# Союз в значении законный брак может быть "освящённым"? Слово на месте?

Tags: выбор-слов

"Её стряпня соблазнила угольщика, который держал лавку напротив. Вступив в освящённый союз, они открыли ресторан".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Союз, в который вступают, бывает освящён церковью, это нормально. Жить можно в "освящённом союзе", а вот вступить в "(уже) освящённый"... Что-то в этом есть от лукавого "сохранить как обновлённый". Очень подозрительный стиль, небезупречный.

Comment: Варьянты, пожалуйста!

Comment: Когда их союз был освящён (церковью; можно без этого, а можно и простонародно "церковно освящён"), они открыли ресторан

Comment: А не вариант ли (чтобы минимально править автора): "Вступив в освящённый ***церковью*** союз, они открыли ресторан"?

Comment: Тогда лучше им "обвенчаться" (Обвенчавшись, ...). Мне не нравится грамматическая последовательность:  вступить в то, что освящено ("вступить в заверенный печатью брак" - то же самое).

Comment: Будем думать, отправим автору. Спасибо!

Comment: Может "освятив свой союз"?

Comment: Посредством церкви?

Comment: Ну да, "освятив свой союз в церкви...."

Comment: После "стряпни" высоковатого стиля слово получится, и ещё нужно учитывать, что в строгом смысле даже куличи "освящает" духовное лицо; обвенчаться - более нейтральное выражение.

Comment: В оригинале то же  "высоковатый" стиль, может с долей юмора?

Comment: Наверное, можно рискнуть.